# migration from html4 to html5

Tags: css, asp.net, html

I have an application developed in VS2005 and html4. First of all my question is, is there any tool that will do migration from html4 to html5.

My plan is first select HTML5 from dropdown available in VS2012 then just change the doctype definition from master page to `<!DOCTYPE html>` and fix all the warning like replace cell padding with padding and etc.

Does these steps are sufficient in order to convert an application in to `HTTML5`?

Comment: Why should you do that?

Comment: @Luïs in order to implement localstorage,offline caching and all new features available in HTML5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are these steps are sufficient in order to convert an application in to HTML5?

In short, yes, that's pretty much it.

HTML5 is explicitly designed to be backward compatible with HTML4; there is very little that you should need to change apart from the doctype.

There are a few things to be aware of, which might need changing:

- A few older HTML tags have been deprecated in HTML5. You can't use things like `<blink>`, `<marquee>` or other awful things like that. Hopefully you weren't using them anyway though?
- Also some attributes have been deprecated, mostly in favour of using CSS instead. So if you're using `width` or `height` or `color` attributes in your HTML tags, you should replace them with CSS. The same also applies to the `<font>` tag; use CSS to define your fonts and font sizes instead.
- There are various new tags in HTML5 which you may want to use. These are tags like `<section>` and `<footer>`, which are designed to make your site's code more readable for search engines. But you don't have to use them; they are entirely optional. Note that IE8 and earlier don't support them unless you use a JavaScript hack, so if you need to support IE8, it may be best not to use these tags. You can still use the HTML5 doctype in IE8 though.

You might find it useful to read the official documentation from the W3C that details the differences between HTML4 and HTML5. Read it here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/